# how to display files with permission number in mac terminal?

Tags: macos, ls

I have tried:

```
stat -c '%a %n' *
```

this does display what I want, but this runs in amazon ec2.

Im running on my mac, when I tried to run:

```
sh-3.2# stat -c '%a %n' *
stat: illegal option -- c
usage: stat [-FlLnqrsx] [-f format] [-t timefmt] [file ...]
sh-3.2#
```

The format that I would like to see is:

```
755 app
644 artisan
755 bootstrap
644 composer.json
644 composer.lock
755 config
755 credentials
755 database
644 package.json
644 package-lock.json
644 phpunit.xml
755 public
755 resources
755 routes
644 server.php
777 storage
755 tests
755 vendor
644 webpack.mix.js
777 worker.log
644 yarn.lock
```

This displays if I used this command `stat -c '%a %n' *` in AWS ec2 linux instance.

Comment: StackExchange is the wrong place for [this type of question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), try asking on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com)

Comment: You want `stat -f "%p %N" someFile`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I want all files to list like ls

Comment: Oh, use `ls` then `ls -l| awk '{$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=""}1'`

Comment: Or use **homebrew** to install `findutils`, then do `gfind -printf "%M %p\n"`

Comment: ls -l| awk '{$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=$8=""}1' doesnt work, it doesnt display like 644, 755, 777

Comment: My first suggestion displays like `644` so use that, or better still, edit your question and show the format you would like!

Comment: @MarkSetchell i updated my question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hopefully this will work for you:

```
stat -f "%p %N" * | awk '{$1=substr($1,length($1)-2)}1'
755 Benchmark
755 BoundedBuffer
755 CImgGenerateVideo
755 CImgInterpolate
755 Flask
755 Folder
644 LUT.png
755 Mosquitto
644 MrBean.jpg
755 ThreadSync
644 URLs.txt
```

Comment: amazing! this is the one!